# Does ice have to be on both poles?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, climate, weather, ice

If an Earth-like planet has ice, does the ice have to be on both poles? For example, could a planet have ice on its south pole but not on the north pole, year-round?

Comment: Wait [15 years](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/article/arctic-summer-sea-ice-could-be-gone-by-2035) and you'll find out first hand!

Comment: @Bohemian The Arctic Ocean may be ice-free in summer in 15 years, but Greenland won't be.

Comment: @gerrit Just because Earth has a large landmass at both poles doesn't mean every planet has to.

Comment: @chepner The land area of Antarctica is nearly 7 times larger than Greenland. Maps of the northern hemisphere using the Mercator projection give a false impression of how big Greenland is.

Comment: @alephzero Nevertheless, it's still the second largest ice cap on the planet and enough to raise global sea levels by around 6 metre.  It counts as a northern polar ice cap.

Comment: There is only ice on the poles because earth is, spoken from a planetary geological era pov, technically in an "ice age" -> the definition for that is there is ice on the poles. There were and will be times that are considered "warm periods" where the poles are ice-free. Last time was I think when the super-continent pangea existed and antarctica was somewhere at the aequator

Comment: @chepner lol earth has only land masses on 1 pole, unless you count siberia as "on pole"

Comment: @clockw0rk I was being loose with "on"; my point was that Earth just happens to have land near the North Pole; not every planet would (nor did Earth at every point in its history).

Comment: @Bohemian https://nypost.com/2020/01/10/the-telling-tale-of-glacier-national-parks-gone-by-2020-signs/ - also "The North Pole will be ice-free in the summer by 2013 because of man-made global warming." - Al Gore, 2009

Comment: @SurpriseDog political rhetoric crafted to garner votes has little credibility, however all data agrees that the North Pole ice is steadily shrinking and thinning. Unless we change how we live, it’s a matter of when, not if, it melts completely.

Comment: Point being: "Prediction is very difficult, especially if it's about the future." -Niels Bohr

Answer (score 17):

All other factors being even? It *might* be possible if one pole was entirely oceanic and the other was either landlocked (like the North Pole) or covered by a continental land mass (like the South Pole)

If you distribute the land mass on your globe so that most of it is concentrated in one hemisphere (like the Earth is now but more so) and then place the other pole more or less centered in the middle of a 'pacific' sized ocean?

Since warm water currents tend to travel in the top layers of the ocean and cold currents, being denser tend to sink towards the bottom there would in principal nothing to stop heat exchange preventing an oceanic ice sheet covering the entire pole from ever forming given there's no land mass to 'seed' from and any ice that does form will be in constant motion.

Note; you would probably still get **grease ice/slush** (frozen sea water) forming in winter but since it would be driven into more or less constant motion by mid oceanic winds, waves and currents it wouldn't necessarily get the chance to form into dense sheets of **pack ice**. So in winter you'd at worst you get a giant  polar slushy. Pack ice forming even in small patches would be a rare/freak event.

One last problem: continental drift means this state of affairs won't last forever. Eventually enough land mass will 'drift' south to interfere with the processes I described and you'll get fixed ice fields at both poles again, even if its the case that one is much smaller than the other

Comment: “Giant polar slushie” - Mmmm, sea salt flavour, my favourite!

Comment: I'd add a touch of caramel. But yes!

Comment: You wouldn't even need a larger Arctic Ocean, just no mountains in Greenland and eastern Canada.  Compare the low-lying coastal lands in Alaska & eastern Siberia: no permanent ice.

Comment: [Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_of_Mars#/media/File:Mars_topography_(MOLA_dataset)_with_poles_HiRes.jpg) could work, having its land mass concentrated in its southern hemisphere.  Now, if only it had an ocean...

Answer (score 12):

No. It’s possible to have ice on only one pole.

Take Earth for example: Its south pole is much colder than its north pole and will have ice long after the Arctic has melted. To quote the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antarctica#Regional_climate):

> Antarctica is colder than the Arctic for three reasons. First, much of
> the continent is more than 3,000 m (9,800 ft) above sea level, and
> temperature decreases with elevation in the troposphere. Second, the
> Arctic Ocean covers the north polar zone: the ocean's relative warmth
> is transferred through the icepack and prevents temperatures in the
> Arctic regions from reaching the extremes typical of the land surface
> of Antarctica. Third, the Earth is at aphelion in July (i.e., the
> Earth is farthest from the Sun in the Antarctic winter), and the Earth
> is at perihelion in January (i.e., the Earth is closest to the Sun in
> the Antarctic summer). The orbital distance contributes to a colder
> Antarctic winter (and a warmer Antarctic summer) but the first two
> effects have more impact.

Comment: Most northern hemisphere ice is on Greenland and not in the Arctic Ocean.  Greenland may still melt well before Antarctica, but it will take much much longer than sea ice melt.

Answer (score 9):

Planets with ice only on one pole almost certainly exist, in case of cold planets tidally locked to a parent star, so that the same side always faces the star (just like the Moon is tidally locked to the Earth and we always see the same side of the Moon, unless we travel beyond it).  Such planets are called [eyeball planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyeball_planet).

An artist impression of [TRAPPIST-1f](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRAPPIST-1f) is mostly covered in ice, including around the equator, but has an ocean on the pole facing the parent star:

[image: artist impression of TRAPPIST-1f]
*Source: NASA [via Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:TRAPPIST-1f_Artist%27s_Impression.png) (public domain)*

Comment: It sounds like an eyeball planet doesn't have a day though. If it's tidally locked to its star, it would rotate once per year. What are such a planet's north and south poles? Does that term still have a meaning?

Comment: @DuncanC: when viewing the distant stars from an eyeball planet, most stars appear to make big circles in the sky (making a complete circle once a year), but there will be two directions where the distant stars move very little -- like Polaris and the Southern Cross from Earth. An eyeball planet does have north and south poles, aligned with those two directions.

Comment: @DavidCary if you define the poles this way, then both would have the same temperature. Even if it's just one giant circum-longitudal iceberg, both poles would have it.

Comment: @JohnDvorak: I agree. The obvious warm near-side pole and the opposite cold-side pole in this illustration have a different definition than the standard definition of the north geographic pole and the south geographic pole, and are located in very different places -- much like the Earth's south geographic pole, Earth's south magnetic-dip pole, and Earth's geomagnetic pole are in measurably different places.

Comment: If we're going by magnetic poles, then you can easily have two poles, one on the equator (no ice) and one near the rotation axis (ice). Or four poles, of which one has ice, or... (not forever, but for long enough for the story to take place)

Answer (score 7):

With just a bit bigger orbital eccentricity, you would get milder winters and colder summers on the "perihelion-winter" hemisphere, and vice versa on the "aphelion-winter" one. This might be enough to put the latter into permanent ice sheet period, especially considering the perihelion season is shorter.

The rotation axis will however drift because of precession, thus the arrangement is not stable.

Comment: We already have milder winters on the perihelion-winter hemisphere.

Answer (score 4):

If the planet's rotational axis is rotated enough (think Uranus, which is spinning on its side), sure. You'd effectively have a tidally locked planet spinning with one pole always facing the star, the other never getting light (unless you're in some sort of binary or more complex system of course in which case it might get some light from the other members of that system).

Maybe not the scenario you're looking for, as that planet'd have some pretty wild climate and weather conditions leading to large parts of it to be unsuitable for life, but there you have it.

Another one might be having one pole being situated on a very large continent, and the other on open ocean, combined with ocean currents and winds that keep one of the polar zones at above freezing temperature for the entire year. Not sure whether that's physically possible though. On earth for example the Gulfstream is pretty strong but not strong enough to keep the north pole free of ice.

Comment: Axial tilt wouldn't be enough, you'd also need to be tidally locked. Even if your axis is on the ecliptic you'd see the sun on each pole, just half a year apart. Each hemisphere would go through a 'summer' where the direct sun would melt the polar cap, so... partially yes? :)

Comment: You seem to be imagining that the planet would spin on its axis while simultaneously have one of its poles always pointing to the star. It doesn't work like that - the axis of rotation doesn't change over the year due to conservation of angular momentum. A planet like Uranus  has seasons just like Earth, only more extreme, with one pole facing the star for half the year before it switches to the other pole. As @Corey said you'd have to be tidally locked instead, and then there wouldn't be any days.

Comment: Your first scenario is called an [Eyeball planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyeball_planet) and probably exists on exoplanets.  Not sure if tidally locked planets can be stable in binary systems.

Comment: TIL Uranus is spinning on its side.

Answer (score 3):

You could have asymmetrical ice coverage if the water at the two poles had a large difference in salinity.  The more salt in the water, the lower the freezing point.  For example, if you had several large rivers or aquifers that emptied into the ocean very near one of the poles, the water there would be more [brackish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brackish_water), would have lower salinity, and would freeze at higher temperatures.

Diverging plate boundaries in one of the polar regions can create thermal vents.  This added heat can keep the water above the freezing point, or can create currents that keep the water moving and resist freezing.

Comment: Was going to make this same point but with a land-mass instead.  Salty ocean on one end, "pure" rainfall water on the other.  "For saltwater that’s as saturated as it can possibly get (i.e. there’s no way to dissolve any more salt in it no matter how hard you tried), the freezing point is -21.1 degrees Celsius. This is when the saltwater is 23.3% salt (by weight)." from https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=1722

Answer (score 1):

I would think that very possible, for example if your planet had a fairly closed oceanic North pole (as Earth currently does) but an interrupted ocean around the south pole (imagine if South America or Africa actually reached Antarctica. Such a configuration would force warm equatorial water south.

My understanding is that the unbroken ring of ocean surrounding Antarctica basically prevents currents from reaching the continent, that those currents get diverted by the circumpolar current.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to know how similar to the Earth this planet requires to be, if we have a mass and a size, practically equal to the Earth but with a much more inclined axis (perhaps almost horizontal) it could practically have one of the poles perpetually frozen and the other with constant sun.

Comment: How? I do not see a reason (apart from possibly eccentric orbit, but I think you were not referring to this)

Comment: @RadovanGarabík when your rotation axis is not at a 90° angle towards the star but “slanted” instead, the one of the poles ends in perpetual night, and the other in perpetual day. Night = no sunlight = lower temperature. Eccentric orbit has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @MrVocabulary I don't see how it can be "perpetual". Surely in half a year the poles trade their places as far as the illumination is concerned, don't they?

Comment: @RadovanGarabík Not if it's tidally locked.  See [Eyeball planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eyeball_planet).

Comment: @gerrit Then it cannot have (much of) an inclined axis - these two are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @RadovanGarabík tidal locking has nothing to do with it. Tidal locking only means one half of the planet always faces the sun as it rotates in sync. Still, this describes rotation around it's own axis, not how the axis is positioned. I am talking about the axis being slanted, i.e. like Uranus: https://www.space.com/13231-planet-uranus-knocked-sideways-impacts.html → this simply means that it rotates along the line of its ring, while one of the poles (these are delimited by the axis) always faces away from the sun.

Comment: @MrVocabulary I see... this is a common mistake. Not only Uranus DOES change its illuminated pole, such an arrangement as you describe is forbidden by the conservation of angular momentum.

Comment: @RadovanGarabík you are right, it does change seasons. But I fail to understand why a planet cannot have a stable inclined axis for a larger period of time. Does it have to rotate along its own axis the way it rotates around a star? Is it just wobbling and tidal locking?

Comment: @MrVocabulary No wobbling nor tidal locking, those are 2nd order effects. The axis is stable in an (approximately) inertial frame of reference (i.e. fixed to the distant stars), thus if it points to the central star at certain spot in the orbit, it will point *away* from the star at the opposite spot.

Comment: @RadovanGarabík oh, I see it now. Díky moc :)

Answer (score 0):

Well... yes, but actually no.
The poles are generally colder than other areas on a planet due their orientation with respect to the body they are orbiting. However, this could be overcome by points with high geothermic energy around the poles. These points could be natural hot springs, large volcanos, etc....

Comment: Welcome to the site Husam, we invite you to take our [tour] and refer to the [help] as and when for guidance to our ways, enjoy worldbuilding.